# Pagination algorithm that doesn't allow a page to be too big or small

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, pagination

I want to write a pagination algorithm that evenly distributes the number of elements per page, with a specified min and max elements per page. When possible, I wanted to have the maximum number of elements per page that it can have without violating the minimum rule.

I've been trying to write my own version of this for a while, but I get stuck on it when it comes to distributing the elements on the page in a manner that I consider to be aesthetically pleasing. Here's the code of my tests:

```
  describe('paginate()', () => {
    it('puts everything on one page is less than or equal to maximum', () => {
      expect(paginate([1, 2], 1, 8)).toEqual([[1, 2]]);
      expect(paginate([1, 2], 3, 8)).toEqual([[1, 2]]);
      expect(paginate([1, 2], 1, 2)).toEqual([[1, 2]]);
    });

    it('divides everything evenly if there are no remainders on the max', () => {
      expect(paginate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 1, 3)).toEqual([
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
      ]);
      expect(paginate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 1, 2)).toEqual([
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6],
      ]);
    });

    it('merges the last page if there is one left over', () => {
      let outcome = paginate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 2, 4);
      expect(outcome).toEqual([
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7],
      ]);
      outcome = paginate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 2, 4);
      console.log('outcome', outcome);
      expect(outcome).toEqual([
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7],
        [8, 9, 10],
      ]); // THIS TEST FAILS
    });

    it('can reduce page sizes if it makes elements evenly distributed', () => {
      let outcome = paginate(_.range(1, 12), 6, 10);
      expect(outcome).toEqual(
        [
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
        ],
        JSON.stringify(outcome)
      );
      outcome = paginate(_.range(1, 22), 6, 10);
      expect(outcome).toEqual(
        [
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
          [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
          [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
        ],
        JSON.stringify(outcome)
      );
    });
  });
```

Here's my code:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export const paginate = <T>(content: T[], min: number, max: number): T[][] => {
  const length = content.length;
  for (let i = max; i > min; i--) {
    if (length % i === 0 || length % i >= min) {
      const result = _.chunk(content, i);
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    }
  }
  console.log('end');
  return _.chunk(content, min);
};
```

there is only one of my tests failing here, but I don't know how to get it passing:

```
  outcome = paginate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 2, 4);
  console.log('outcome', outcome);
  expect(outcome).toEqual([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7],
    [8, 9, 10],
  ]); // THIS TEST FAILS
```

the output is `[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ], [ 9, 10 ] ]`  instead of what i want. Every time I think of a solution to this problem, it breaks another test. I've been toiling for a few hours now and I'm stuck. **I don't know how to get all these test to pass.** Also, are there any edge cases I may not have thought of?

I'm not tied to the signature I've come up with for this function, so if it makes sense to change it, feel free. For example, I'm not entirely convinced that I need to provide a min at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My inclination would be to do something like this:

```
function paginate<T>(arr: T[], maxPerPage: number): T[][] {
    const numPages = Math.ceil(arr.length / maxPerPage);
    const minPerPage = Math.floor(arr.length / numPages);
    const numBigPages = arr.length % numPages;
    console.log(numPages, minPerPage, numBigPages)
    const ret: T[][] = [];
    for (let pageNum = 0, curElem = 0; pageNum < numPages; pageNum++) {
        const numOnThisPage = minPerPage + (pageNum < numBigPages ? 1 : 0);
        ret.push(arr.slice(curElem, curElem + numOnThisPage));
        curElem += numOnThisPage;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The idea is to only ask for the maximum number of elements per page `maxPerPage`, and determine the number of pages `numPages` by dividing the array length by this maximum, rounding up to a whole number if necessary.

Then the task is to divide the elements into these pages.  Again, you can divide the array length by number of pages `(arr.length / numPages)` and put that many elements into each page.  If that's not a whole number, then some "small" pages will have the whole number less than this, `minPerPage = Math.floor(arr.length / numPages)`, and some "big" pages will have one more, `minPerPage + 1`.  You can calculate the number of big pages `numBigPages` by taking the remainder when dividing the array length by the number of pages.  (If this is confusing, imagine distributing into `numPages` pages one element at a time; you'd end up putting in `minPerPage` into each page, and then you'd have some left over.  You'd likely want no more than one of these leftovers per page, so the number of leftovers equals the number of big pages `numBigPages`.)

So, how do we distribute the leftovers into big pages?  It sounds like you want all the big pages to come first and then all the small pages.  So we just make sure that if the current page number is less than the number of big pages, we make it a big page, and otherwise it's small.

---

Let's see how it does on your examples:

```
const range = (n: number) => Array.from({ length: n }, (_, i) => i + 1);

console.log(JSON.stringify(paginate(range(2), 8))); // [[1,2]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(paginate(range(2), 2))); // [[1,2]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(paginate(range(6), 3))); // [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(paginate(range(6), 2))); // [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

console.log(JSON.stringify(paginate(range(7), 4))); // [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(paginate(range(10), 4))); // [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]

console.log(JSON.stringify(paginate(range(11), 10))); // [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(paginate(range(21), 10)));
// [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19,20,21]]
```

That looks like what you wanted, right?

---

Obviously the exact implementation of that algorithm can change; if you want to use lodash or to make the array via purely functional methods instead of iterating and using `push()`, that's up to you.  But the basic concept seems to match up with what you want. Anyway, hope this lets you proceed.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwIYHMZlVApgHgBUA+AClQCcKAuRQgbQF0AaRAW1QA8AFXC7jLlpgQbAEZ8AlLQaMmiAN4BYAFCJ1iCAgDOURCLYD0ubYgC8iALI4AFgDoIuGABtyVO89xh0UG4gD07Fy8-IKSANyqGpo6emxYIUa45la2dsDOcHAUbhQeXj5+gQZJ2hFRGlpguvqiAEIw6KUplHme3r6IAKS1hoLakWqVOnCeHnDopCX9rPFgiYKsBg1N-ZIV6lU1FLhQMkzyFkyD0cDZiKSeemjGAHKiKQAMrBAgFACinmxP4SiC9998L1Sr8brgAQBqCGSRQbaIxap6AwAeTAhBsMG0SRScwWxkQEIuYIBiCBy0azQA-IgAIyIWiPcpDeGIHZQOzIEDaGy5OzaZwwRykV4fL4vN6fXDfQkotEYrFhJkszYSr4Eiyy9GYpInDQAXzhbLeSDZgwNKlUWz0FFQ3mSFimwlEEgoMLMxEQAEEqKgAJ7pChwNikBSIdqFYSIPWsUgAfVYMDdHpgBNpTMtIzGmUmACkAMrI258qAULCYYC+0g3LA4XCkG120gAJkkrAAHJJO79-IF6PQacwm4xGBnqqNcONcwWi7pS94YBWqxga3h67bjM3W4gW12Ar3+4Ph6PtOPJ6R84Xi3Py5Xq9hVw2NwA2LcAZk7ET3iD7A6bzFfLD0AALMwACszBPsOiDHqe2bntOV5lgut7LvedaPnWL6sDun49t+B5Dsw9CvswQGAeBkEjhaKhbLBEzwZes5IYud61mujYAOxbkBH7dvuv7-qR5EQcwHFHjRmYTnBF4ziWzEoZgaHsRuNKMqwPG7nhP6DoJZFERRomAW2zAAJzMKp4kwVm9EyYh84sahbEYaQNI0luqm8V+2l-iRIEUYBHHMMZZmqeZNLibR1lToxcn2QpK7oeudZNm5rAeV2qhaQRulgSJYlEcF5nPK55l-jSJE0np-bgTST7mYFNLGTSZlNs8KXiUAA)

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I wanted.I thought I figured it out, but by running your algorithm, I discovered one of my tests (not shown here) had a bug in it.  Plus, i was using recursion and it was really inefficient. Thank you for taking the time to answer this